# ¿Como puedo ingresar los datos de una consulta de una base de datos en mysql en un menu de salto?

Tags: php, html

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    <select id="nom" name="nom">
    <option value="1"> .$row['nombre']. </option>
    </select>
}
```

[image: Asi es como quiero que quede, y que en lugar de donde dice "Nombre 1" salga el primer nombre que tengo en mi base de datos]

Lo que busco, es que los datos de mi tabla aparezcan en el menu de salto, que en lugar de "Nombre 1" diga "Alejandro" que seria el primer nombre que contiene mi base de datos, el problema es que no se porque no acepta el comando select.

Comment: Coloca el código no la imagen

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asegurate de colocar el código la próxima vez, es más fácil.

No te acepta la impresión del select porque las instrucciones

```
<select name="nom" id="nom">
    <option value="1">.$row['nombre'].</option>
</select>
```

no son del lenguaje php, debes de colocar todo sobre texto de la siguiente forma

```
echo '<select id="nom" name="nom">';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=\"1\">{$row['nombre']}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```